# How to remove something common from each row of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have a pandas Dataframe with two columns. One of the columns is the Timestamp. The time is in the format 
2019-05-27 05:00:00+0530, with +0530 being present in each row of the column. How do I remove the '+0530' from each row of that column?

```
#import csv
df= pd.read_csv("data_2.csv")

#Head of the Data
df.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy string element-wise [replace](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.replace.html#numpy.core.defchararray.replace)

```py
#import csv
import numpy as np

df= pd.read_csv("data_2.csv")
df['Timestamp'] = np.replace(df['Timestamp'], '+0530', '')

df.head()
```

Comment: It shows AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 0):

You can also do, [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
df['Timestamp'] = df['Timestamp'].str.replace('+0530', '')
```